# virtual Operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making a GVector class that contains will further derive into 3 types i.e
PVector (Pixel Space Vector)
MVector (Meter Space Vector)
RVector (Rendering Space Vector)

```
class GVector {
  public : 
    eVectorSpace eVS; // Defines which space the vector would be
    float x,y; // The x and y values of a 2-Dimensional vector
    ...
    GVector operator+ (const GVector& v) const { return GVector(x+v.x, y+v.y, v.eVS); }
    ...
};

class MVector {
  public :
    PVector toPVector() {...}
    //Will contain functions to convert the same vector into a different space
};
```

I want to make it possible to add 2 vectors lying in the same space

```
MVector operator+ (const MVector& v) const { return MVector(x+v.x, y+v.y); }
```

Do I need to make the base class function like this ?

```
virtual GVector* operator+ (const GVector* v) const () = 0;
```

But I would like to return a vector in the same space as the two adding vectors.

The function of adding the values of the x,y are same for each type of vector.
Is there a way to minimize this into the base class itself ?
Or is there a better approach to adding vectors in the same space and converting them into different spaces ?

Comment: What if vectors in different spaces are operated upon?

Comment: I want to do operations on a vector lying in the same space only. If they lie on a different space then I was planning to convert them using a conversion ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes no sense to perform operations on two different children then the operator should **not** be defined on the parent. Instead a protected helper function can be defined, and then the children should implement the operator separately, delegating to the helper function.

Comment: Do you mean protected : GVector add(const GVector&) const { return a GVector; } and then in the respective children classes call this method and then typecast them into the required return types ?
What if there was a need to perform operations on different children ? In the base class there is a enum that stores which space it would be in. I could use that to check and do the operations. If so what other suggestions could you offer? Thanks

Comment: You don't need *both* the children *and* the field to describe which space it's in; you should use one or the other as appropriate.

Comment: Oh.. can you explain why it would be a bad idea so I could prevent this architecture in the future.

Comment: It's redundant. The type already *is* a flag of sorts, except it's the *compiler* that checks it instead of the code.

Comment: How do I choose which will be better in this scenario if I need to perform operations on vector on different spaces? Also I need to be able to convert them into different spaces.

Comment: I think I would stick with the enum idea for now as it would give me more flexibility. I approved this answer as it helped me to get to a solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is already type information available without using an enum.  `dynamic_cast<MVector*>(pointer)` will return a pointer only if the object pointed to by `pointer` is of type `MVector` or a class derived from `MVector`; it will return NULL in all other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Some code somewhere needs to know how to add two of the vector objects together, but it doesn't actually need to be the vector types themselves. You can define a set of addition operators outside the classes.

```
MVector operator+(const MVector &left, const MVector &right) {
    return MVector(left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y);
}
```

You can define as many different operator adds like this as you want, so long as the compiler can figure out what the types are without ambiguity. You can even provide implementations that accept a `MVector` and a `GVector`.

```
MVector operator+(const MVector &left, const RVector &right) {
    MVector tmp = right.toMVector();
    return MVector(left.x + tmp.x, left.y + tmp.y);
}
```